# Is Azure Bastion common across resource groups?

Tags: azure-bastion

I have two resource groups(RG1 and RG2 ) and I am using Azure Bastion in RG2 and I don't want Azure Bastion in RG1(old Resource group).

Can I delete Azure Bastion from RG1 with out affecting RG2.
I dread if it affects my Bastion setup in RG2(New Resource Group)

Answer (score 1):

In theory, when you delete a ressource from a ressource group, the others ressources group will not be affected.

Actually, you can delete your RG1 bastion without affecting your RG2 Bastion setup.

Here's some ways to delete your Bastion with Azure Cli or Powershell :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/bastion?view=azure-cli-latest#az-network-bastion-delete

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/remove-azbastion?view=azps-9.7.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-9.1.0